# Как сохранить переданные данные с помощью intent.putExtra в бд?

Tags: android

Cтрока переданная методом putExtra в другое активити не сохраняется в бд.

Передающая активность:

```
public void onClickKvartAdd(View v) {

        Intent addKvart = new Intent(this, Kvartiry.class); 
//      addKvart.putExtra("kvartName", atvKvart.getText().toString());

        startActivityForResult(addKvart, RESULT_OK);
      }
```

Код принимающей активности:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent zaselenie = new Intent();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etName.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(Kvartiry.this, "Данные не введены",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    saveState();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, zaselenie);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
@Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

             Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) { 
                    String kvartName = extras.getString("kvartName");
                    etName.setText(kvartName);

        }
        }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(KvartDB._ID, rowId);
    }

    private void saveState() {

        String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem();

        String kvartira = etName.getText().toString();

        String city = etCity.getText().toString();
        String street = etStreet.getText().toString();
        String home = etHome.getText().toString();
        String kv = etKvartira.getText().toString();
        String price = etPrice.getText().toString();

        if (kvartira.length() == 0 && street.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (rowId == null) {
            long id = kdb.createNewKvart(category, kvartira, city, street, home, kv, price);
            if (id > 0) {
                rowId = id;

            }
        } else {
            kdb.updateKvart(rowId, category, kvartira, city, street, home, kv, price);
        }

    }
```

Код DB:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
    KvartDB kdb;

    // константы для конструктора
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kvart_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "kvartiry_table";

    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "kvartira";
    public static final String CITY_COLUMN = "city";
    public static final String STREET_COLUMN = "street";
    public static final String HOME_COLUMN = "home";
    public static final String KVARTIRA_COLUMN = "kv";
    public static final String PRICE_COLUMN = "price";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " + NAME_COLUMN
            + " text not null, " + CITY_COLUMN + " text not null, "
            + STREET_COLUMN + " text not null, " + HOME_COLUMN + " integer, "
            + KVARTIRA_COLUMN + " integer, " + PRICE_COLUMN + " integer "
            + ");";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
            + TABLE_NAME;

    public KvartDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public KvartDB(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, errorHandler);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
//      db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(KvartDB.class.getName(), "Обновление базы данных с версии " + oldVersion
                + " до версии " + newVersion
                + ", которое удалит все старые данные");
        // Удаляем предыдущую таблицу при апгрейде
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
//      db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES2);
        // Создаём новый экземпляр таблицы
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Создаёт новый элемент списка дел. Если создан успешно - возвращается
     * номер строки rowId, иначе -1
     */

    public long createNewKvart(String category, String kvartira, String city, String street, String home, String kv,
            String price) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(category, kvartira, city, street, home, kv, price);

    long row = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
    db.close();

    return row;

}

    /**
     * Обновляет список
     */

    public boolean updateKvart(long rowId, String category, String kvartira, String city, String street, String home, String kv,
            String price) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues updateValues = createContentValues(category, kvartira, city, street, home, kv, price);

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, updateValues, _ID + "=" + rowId,
                null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Удаляет элемент списка
     */
    public void deleteKvart(long rowId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает курсор со всеми элементами списка дел
     * 
     * @return курсор с результатами всех записей
     */
    public Cursor getAllKvart() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, COLUMN_CATEGORY, NAME_COLUMN, CITY_COLUMN, STREET_COLUMN, HOME_COLUMN,
                KVARTIRA_COLUMN, PRICE_COLUMN }, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает курсор с указанной записи
     */
    public Cursor getKvart(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        return db.query(true, TABLE_NAME,
                new String[] { COLUMN_CATEGORY, NAME_COLUMN, CITY_COLUMN, STREET_COLUMN, HOME_COLUMN,
                KVARTIRA_COLUMN, PRICE_COLUMN }, _ID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    private ContentValues createContentValues(String category, String kvartira, String city, String street, String home, String kv,
            String price) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
        cv.put(NAME_COLUMN, kvartira);
        cv.put(CITY_COLUMN, city);
        cv.put(STREET_COLUMN, street);
        cv.put(HOME_COLUMN, home);
        cv.put(KVARTIRA_COLUMN, kv);
        cv.put(PRICE_COLUMN, price);
        return cv;
    }

}
```

Comment: А где тут сохранение в БД? Я вижу лишь получение переданной строки из `Bundle` и назначение её `EditText`'у.

----

*[offtop]*
Названия классов вроде `Kvartiry`, заставляют мои глаза кровоточить. Неужели настолько тяжко с английским?
*[/offtop]*

Comment: А что если данные были переданы не через `putExtra`, то они пишутся в БД? Вы научитесь хотя бы правильно формулировать вопрос и отделять мух от котлет. Да и солидарен с @falstaf - где тут сохранение на БД?

Comment: Если я в передающей активности убираю строку addKvart.putExtra("kvartName", atvKvart.getText().toString()); то конечно ничего не передается, но все что я ввожу вручную, все сохраняется.. Если же присутствует эта строка, то передача происходит, но результат не сохраняется в БД.

Comment: @zloyel, прошу прощения, а вы знаете такое слово, как "отладчик"? Сдаётся мне, беглый прогон вашего кода под ним позволит без особых проблем выявить причину проблемы. Видите ли, в чём дело: да, вы добавили код сохранения в БД, но понятнее-то от этого не стало. Что за волшебный `kdb`? Как устроены изнутри `createNewKvart` и `updateKvart`? В какую ветку `if`'а заходит выполнение?

Comment: Вы очень не нападайте, это моя первая попытка, поэтому миллион вопросов на каждом повороте :(

Comment: @zloyel, ок, попробуйте тогда хотя бы логирование понавтыкать в условия, таким образом вы увидите, куда заходит выполнение и что происходит.